Game Theory problem: 2x3 matrix where one of the cells tends to infinity
I'm currently revising for a Linear Programming exam and found this problem on a past paper:

Parts A and b are clear to me. My issue comes with parts c and d. My rough solution looks like this: 
At this point, I conclude that the row player should maximise their worst case by choosing p=1 which leads the column player to choose C2 with the value of the game being 4. Is this correct? if not, where have I gone wrong? I haven't encountered this type of problem yet in lectures or exercises.
Part D is also interesting. My approach was to go back to the original matrix and reduce again, leaving:
Once again, I'd like to highlight that these are rough attempts and that I'd write the steps more clearly in an exam, I'm more interested in understanding how to approach the question just in case something similar comes up in the exam. Thanks!

In part (c), your dominance reduction is not finished.

Thanks, I see that now. C3 is now dominated by C1 so that can be removed. With this, the row player can play R2 every time and the column player plays C1, so the value is now 5?

Please don't use images for math or text.  Please transcribe them to text and Mathjax.

Please ask only one question per post.

For part (d), your $2{\times}3$ matrix result is correct.

For part (c), assuming $x > 7$, your dominance reduction to a $2{\times}3$ matrix is valid, but a further dominance reduction is possible, yielding the $2{\times}2$ matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
4&6\\
x&3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and since $x > 4$ (we have already assumed $x > 7$), the optimal strategy is a mixed strategy.

Leaving $x$ unknown, we get
\begin{align*}
C_1(p)&=4p+x(1-p)\\[4pt]
C_2(p)&=6p+3(1-p)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
for which the optimal value of $p$ is
$$
p^*=\frac{x-3}{x-1}
$$
which yields
$$
\frac{6x-12}{x-1}
$$
as the value of the game.

Hence as $x$ approaches infinity, the value of the game approaches $6$.
